# Excel macro, add-in work with different books

Tags: macros

I have an issue with my macro. The code is working when I use it in new macro (I create new macro in Book1, and paste code there) and activate macro from this Book1.

Things are getting harder when I've solved using add-in (new group in ribbon,called "MyOwnGroup" contains one button "MyOwnButton"). And I really need you advice here.

So, what I try to do and what happens.

1) How it works without add-in.
I select range in Book2, press ALT+F8 and just activate macro of Book1. Selected range is copied to Book1. 
Inside the macro Book1 is ThisWorkBook, and Book2 is ActiveWorkBook. I mean macro has 2 different references: to ThisWorkBook (where code is) and ActiveWorkbook when I copy range.

2) With add-in the things are different, because now I have 3 Books:

- Book1 (I need to paste selected range from other book to this one)
- Book2 with selected range
- Workbook.xlam which contains code of my macro

ThisWorkBook is now Workbook.xlam because it containts code.

ActiveWorkbook is a book with selected range.

Book1 where to I try to paste values is uknown for macro, I can't get a reference of it...

For e.g.

I open my Book1 (and Workbook.xlam with macro opens as well) then I open Book2. I select range in Book2, activate Book1 and press "MyOwnButton". The selection from Book2 (from activebook) must be copied and pasted to Book1 (without add in it is ThisWorkBook), but I can't get reference to Book1, because ThisWorkBook is Workbook.xlam and ActiveWorkBook is Book2. They are already engaged.

Is there way to get reference of Book1 in this case?

Comment: You definitely can tell the macro to use the 'currently active' workbook (that is not ThisWorkBook; something else)

Comment: "Is there way to get reference of Book1 in this case?"  - if you've opened also book11 and book1111 how you want Excel to know you need to use Book1?? If you're sure that you've opened only two workbooks, then you can loop through `Application.Workbooks` and use the one which is not the same as `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: It is nice idea to use loop! But will the loop detect book.xlam or not?